# error for semantic in emacs 23.3 with integrated cedet

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

Here is the version of cedet I am using

```
CEDET Version:  1.0
                Requested   File        Loaded
  Package       Version     Version     Version
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  cedet:        1.0     nil     ok
  eieio:        1.3     nil     ok
  semantic:     2.0     nil     ok
  srecode:      1.0     nil     Not Loaded
  ede:          1.0     nil     ok
  speedbar:     1.0     nil     ok

  emacs version 23.3.1
```

When I run "M-x semantic-ia-fast-jump", I got the error:

```
  Wrong type argument: stringp, (((0) "ptrdiff_t"))
```

Anybody knows why? It's definitely not because the data type of the variable is "ptrdiff_t".

Comment: M-x toggle-debug-on-error. paste full debugger message here. so people can understand whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for version 23.x it still better to use [version from BZR](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/bzr-repo.shtml) as it incorporates more fixes for C++, plus many other improvements... Details on installation & customization you can find in [this article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html).

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Just don't understand why emacs developpers did this. The builtin cedet doesn't improve in emacs 24.092 either. Yes, I just gave up the builtin cedet.

Comment: It's too much changes were made when integrating CEDET to Emacs, and CEDET's developers are testing now new branch, where all changes are merged - this should simplify merging with Emacs in future (I hope that this will happen before 24.1 release)